Which book is this chapter on "Rational Approximation" from?
Finding "Rational Approximation" on Google gives this pdf and it is a very good text for the introduction and has been referred to answer the questions of math stack exchange as well. I really like the style of this book and would love to read the rest of the chapters as well.
Can anyone please help me with the book's name? I've attached a screenshot of the first page here.
Edit: Roots to Research by J. D. Sally.


I guess you're new to the internet? One thing you can try is to delete portions of the URL a little at a time and see if that takes you to a "parent page", but not so much so that you don't know the book. I tried this and it didn't work. Another thing to try is to simply do a google phrase search for some of the text material. Doing this for "Every point on the real line corresponds, as we know, to a real number" and searching in Google-Books (obvious choice, since you want the book's title) gave me this.

@DaveL.Renfro Ah, thanks a lot. I did everything except searching in Google-Books. My bad :(

Sorry for the bit of snarkiness, but I was rather surprised that what was to me the obvious thing to do wasn't done (since when I did it, I got the book's title). But maybe my not having access to paywalls and such leads me to be a bit more resourceful in looking things up. By the way, if the phrase I used did not work, then I would have tried another phrase. Sometimes a long phrase doesn't work as well as a uniquely-sounding shorter phrase. But before doing that, I decided first to simply take the easiest phrase for copying from the .pdf.

No problem. Thanks for the advice :))

@Dave, a simple change does it: https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-48

The book is Roots to Research by Judith D. Sally and Paul J. Sally, Jr.

